# Initial position for PKToolPicker (PencilKit)?

Tags: ios, ios13, ipados, apple-pencil, pencilkit

How to setup PKToolPicker initial position?

It always started at the bottom, and if there is a toolbar, cover up the toolbar.

```
let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: self.view.window!)
toolPicker?.addObserver(canvas)
toolPicker?.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
```

Comment: No one? It would be really useful if I could start this on the right side. Or even just have it do a .off(y:-10) would work but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: It's been awhile! I would also like to open on the right side instead of just the bottom if possible. Nothing in the docs but wondering if anyone had a suggestion?

Comment: It's not possible on iPhone to change the picker's position but I think it's possible on iPad, although I don't really know how.